# Copiar linha para uma tabela idêntica - mySQL

Tags: mysql

Bom, possuo 2 tabelas identicas no banco mySQL, aonde eu cadastrei fotos em uma, e esqueci da outra. Como faço para copiar os dados do campo `foto` da **TABLE 1** para **TABLE 2**. Porém somente na que o campo `nome` for iguais em ambas.

> **TABLE 1 =** pacientes **TABLE 2 =** pacientes.backup

**Tentei esse código, porém não está reconhecendo a partir do `WHERE`.**

```
 INSERT INTO pacientes_backup (foto) SELECT foto from pacientes WHERE pacientes_backup.nome = pacientes.nome;
```

Comment: Assumindo que são todas as fotos e que estão na mesma ordem. Pode ser assim: `INSERT INTO pacientes_backup (foto) SELECT foto from pacientes`

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, beleza? então cara, é por que a TABLE 2, possui mais registros do que a TABLE 1...

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa ficar muito atento ao campo que utilizará como chave, pois pode acabar atualizando todas as linhas da tabela backup e, aparentemente, não é o que quer. Utilizei tabelas temporárias para ilustrar a solução:

```
DECLARE @pacientes TABLE (Nome VARCHAR(20), Foto VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @pacientes_backup TABLE (Nome VARCHAR(20), Foto VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @pacientes VALUES ('Ronaldo', 'exame.jpg')
INSERT INTO @pacientes_backup VALUES ('Ronaldo',null)


SELECT * 
  FROM @pacientes

SELECT * 
  FROM @pacientes_backup -- SEM FOTO

UPDATE pb SET pb.Foto = p.Foto --ATUALIZANDO A LINHA DA TABELA BACKUP COM A FOTO LOCALIZADA NA TABELA PRINCIPAL
  FROM @pacientes p
 INNER JOIN @pacientes_backup pb ON pb.nome = p.nome


SELECT * 
  FROM @pacientes

SELECT * 
  FROM @pacientes_backup -- COM FOTO
```

Você pode observar que não utilizei **INSERT** mas sim **UPDATE** pelo fato da linha **já existir** e não possuir o valor no campo FOTO.

Espero ter ajudado. Bom trabalho.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém, o primeiro `declare` está com erro...

Comment: Legal! Como fiz no SQL Server por ter alguma diferença, mas roda liso no SQL Server. Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

**Funcionando aqui, simples e prático.**

```
UPDATE pacientes_backup
SET pacientes_backup.foto =(SELECT pacientes.foto FROM pacientes WHERE pacientes.nome = pacientes_backup.nome)
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente desta forma, e veja se funcionou:

```
INSERT INTO pacientes_backup_novo(foto)
SELECT p.foto FROM pacientes p, 
      pacientes_backup pk 
WHERE p.nome = pk.nome;
```

Porém antes de o fazer, certifique-se de que o banco esteja vazio, já que se trata de uma inserção e não um update.

E verifique se os demais campos aceitam nulo, pois caso contrário, você não conseguirá executar esta query.

**Importante:** Você está tentando fazer uma inserção comparando um nome que esteja nas duas tabelas, ou seja, nunca irá conseguir, pois se ambas as tabelas possuem dado, você não deve fazer insert, mas atualizar os dados.

Se você deseja importar apenas as fotos de uma tabela para outra, vc pode fazer assim:

```
update pacientes_backup bk set bk.foto = (
select foto from pacientes p inner join pacientes_backup in_bk  on in_bk.nome = p.nome) 
where bk.name = (
select nome from pacientes p inner join pacientes_backup in_bk  on in_bk.nome = p.nome)
```

ou:

```
UPDATE pacientes_backup pk
SET pk.foto =(SELECT p.foto FROM pacientes p WHERE p.nome = pk.nome)
```